# MYSQL NOT IN getting certain column

Tags: mysql

i have mysql query:

```
select * from ( 
    SELECT subject as kodetb FROM 
        vtiger_servicecontracts,vtiger_servicecontractscf, 
        vtiger_crmentity,vtiger_user2role, vtiger_role, 
        vtiger_users,vtiger_leaddetails, vtiger_contactdetails, vtiger_campaign,   
        `vtiger_accounting_payments` vap1, vtiger_accounting va1 
        left join vtiger_accounting va2 on va2.accountingid=va1.accountingid 
        left join vtiger_accounting_payments vap2 
            on va1.accountingid=vap2.idtransaction 
            and va2.accountingtype='Pelunasan Gesek' 
        WHERE vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vap1.idtransaction and 
            va1.accountingrelated2=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid and 
            vtiger_servicecontractscf.servicecontractsid=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid and
            vap1.idtransaction=va1.accountingid and vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0 and
            vtiger_user2role.userid=vtiger_users.id and 
            vtiger_crmentity.smcreatorid=vtiger_user2role.userid and 
            vtiger_user2role.roleid=vtiger_role.roleid and 
            vtiger_users.user_name='stafsda' and cf_1091=leadid and 
            vtiger_contactdetails.contactid=vtiger_servicecontracts.contactid and 
            vtiger_campaign.campaignid=cf_1155 and 
            date_format(vap1.paymentdate,'%Y-%m-%d') = date_format('2016-03-07','%Y-%m-%d') and 
            va1.accountingtype='Pelunasan Bank' and subject 
        NOT IN ( 
            SELECT subject as kodetb FROM 
                vtiger_servicecontracts,vtiger_servicecontractscf, 
                vtiger_crmentity,vtiger_user2role, vtiger_role, 
                vtiger_users,vtiger_leaddetails, vtiger_contactdetails, vtiger_campaign, 
                vtiger_accounting, vtiger_accounting_payments 
            WHERE vtiger_crmentity.crmid=idtransaction and 
                accountingrelated2=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid and 
                vtiger_servicecontractscf.servicecontractsid=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid and 
                idtransaction=accountingid and vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0 and 
                vtiger_user2role.userid=vtiger_users.id and vtiger_crmentity.smcreatorid=vtiger_user2role.userid and 
                vtiger_user2role.roleid=vtiger_role.roleid and vtiger_users.user_name='stafsda' and cf_1091=leadid and 
                vtiger_contactdetails.contactid=vtiger_servicecontracts.contactid and 
                vtiger_campaign.campaignid=cf_1155 and date_format(paymentdate,'%Y-%m-%d') = 
                date_format('2016-03-07' ,'%Y-%m-%d') and accountingtype='Pelunasan Gesek' group by idtransaction
        )
) xyz order by kodetb
```

i have a problem the result of query above is successfully run and display only one column.
when i put another column beside kodetb in both subqueries, it show error message "Operand should contain 1 column(s)".

What i want is to display certain column beside column "kodetb"

Thanks

Comment: What field do you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

If we need to select additional `newcolumn` and also pair (subject, newcolumn) should not be in subquery with condition `NOT IN (...)`, try this code:

```
select * from (
    SELECT subject as kodetb, newcolumn FROM
        vtiger_servicecontracts,vtiger_servicecontractscf,
        vtiger_crmentity,vtiger_user2role, vtiger_role,
        vtiger_users,vtiger_leaddetails, vtiger_contactdetails, vtiger_campaign,
        `vtiger_accounting_payments` vap1, vtiger_accounting va1
        left join vtiger_accounting va2 on va2.accountingid=va1.accountingid
        left join vtiger_accounting_payments vap2
            on va1.accountingid=vap2.idtransaction
            and va2.accountingtype='Pelunasan Gesek'
        WHERE vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vap1.idtransaction and
            va1.accountingrelated2=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid and
            vtiger_servicecontractscf.servicecontractsid=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid and
            vap1.idtransaction=va1.accountingid and vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0 and
            vtiger_user2role.userid=vtiger_users.id and
            vtiger_crmentity.smcreatorid=vtiger_user2role.userid and
            vtiger_user2role.roleid=vtiger_role.roleid and
            vtiger_users.user_name='stafsda' and cf_1091=leadid and
            vtiger_contactdetails.contactid=vtiger_servicecontracts.contactid and
            vtiger_campaign.campaignid=cf_1155 and
            date_format(vap1.paymentdate,'%Y-%m-%d') = date_format('2016-03-07','%Y-%m-%d') and
            va1.accountingtype='Pelunasan Bank' and CONCAT(subject, '--',n ewcolumn)
        NOT IN (
            SELECT CONCAT(subject, '--', newcolumn) as concatsubject FROM
                vtiger_servicecontracts,vtiger_servicecontractscf,
                vtiger_crmentity,vtiger_user2role, vtiger_role,
                vtiger_users,vtiger_leaddetails, vtiger_contactdetails, vtiger_campaign,
                vtiger_accounting, vtiger_accounting_payments
            WHERE vtiger_crmentity.crmid=idtransaction and
                accountingrelated2=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid and
                vtiger_servicecontractscf.servicecontractsid=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid and
                idtransaction=accountingid and vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0 and
                vtiger_user2role.userid=vtiger_users.id and vtiger_crmentity.smcreatorid=vtiger_user2role.userid and
                vtiger_user2role.roleid=vtiger_role.roleid and vtiger_users.user_name='stafsda' and cf_1091=leadid and
                vtiger_contactdetails.contactid=vtiger_servicecontracts.contactid and
                vtiger_campaign.campaignid=cf_1155 and date_format(paymentdate,'%Y-%m-%d') =
                date_format('2016-03-07' ,'%Y-%m-%d') and accountingtype='Pelunasan Gesek' group by idtransaction
        )
) xyz order by kodetb
```

Comment: hello this is columns i want to display DATE_FORMAT(vap1.paymentdate ,'%d/%m/%Y') as tanggal, 
DATE_FORMAT(due_date ,'%d/%m/%Y') as tgljatuhtempo, vtiger_servicecontracts.subject as kodetb, 
vtiger_servicecontracts.contract_type as tipetb, cf_1101 as tb, sum(vap1.amount) as lunasbank , sum(vap1.amount) as totalgesek, vtiger_contactdetails.firstname as namadepan, vtiger_contactdetails.lastname as namabelakang,
vtiger_contactdetails.contactid as memberid,
campaignname as nokk,
cf_1085 as namabank,
cf_1095,
cf_1099 as tagihanbank,
vtiger_leaddetails.lastname as tipekartu

Comment: pls edit your answer because i tried by myself it get error 
#1583 - Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'CONCAT'  . thx